# How to load function from library on page load using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am doing my project using codeigniter

I want load a function when the page loads. i tried to give the function in `__construct()` but i need to call the function at every page.

So i want to call the function which is in library without calling from `__construct()`

Can anyone give me the solution for my problem

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into the [hooks](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html). You can configure a function or a method of a class to be executed in various places in the life cycle of every request, depending in your needs.

If you need the controller instance for your functionality (the `$this` in most contexts) you probably need the `post_controller_constructor` one, and use the `get_instance()` to get a hold of the controller instance inside of the hook, to load in libraries or call models and such.

An other way could be that you extend the `CI_Controller` class with a `MY_Controller` class, place it under `application/core/MY_Controller.php` and move your code inside that classes `__construct` and use the `MY_Controller` as the base class of your regular controllers, as described the [Creating Core System Classes](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html) page.

Answer (score 0):

Add a library in autoload, then in that library file use `__construct` to call your function.

Comment: This doesn't seem like much of an answer, given that the OP asks for a codeigniter answer and you say you don't know how to do that in codeigniter.